# How to add customized themes to Umbraco Articulate?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, articulate

How do I add customized themes to umbraco, because i when look at the templates of the blog content pages, they actually don't have any templates specified.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there isn't really much of a community around theming for Articulate, probably since it's implied that you'll be integrating the blog into an existing website.

Answer (score 0):

VAPOR is the default template:  https://github.com/Shazwazza/Articulate/wiki/Installed-Themes

If you want to see the other templates go to Content Tree > Blog > Style TAB > scroll down you will see a drop down selection showing VAPOR as the default. From here select another template then refresh your page.